# Add Number of Users who have "Recommended Deletion"

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, low-quality-posts

In the current **Suggested Edit Review Queue**, bringing up the `Reject` button shows this dialogue:

[image: Rejecting Edit]

In the current **Low Quality Posts Review Queue**, clicking on the `Recommend Deletion` button shows this dialogue:

[image: Recommend Deletion]

**Could we have a blue box added for number of users who have already marked a certain type of deletion just like in the Edit Rejection dialogue box?**

Comment: I have a feeling this is pulling from the "Flag" system which means changing this in one place would show any normal user the amount of flags when they use the Flag option on a question or answer.  But I'm hoping they can be segregated to help improve the queue.

Comment: I believe the counters *do* show up in the *close vote* dialog, which is awfully similar to the bottom screenshot.

Comment: @retailcoder This dialogue comes from the Low Quality Posts, and it has a button of `Flag Question` which is why it struck me as different (although I don't have access to the Close Vote queue yet so I wouldn't know)

Comment: Something tells me this would break review audits...

Comment: @Won't It works fine in the close vote queue. The data is simply faked, from what i can tell.

Comment: @bluet I think it should trigger for 2k folks then because of access to LQR.

Comment: @bluet I already get the blue number on the Suggested Edit queue.